# ASPNET CORE MVC ROL IDENTITY BASED MENU Dynamic

Tags: asp.net-mvc, aplicación-web, c#-8.0, asp.net-core-mvc

Como podrían crearse menús dinámicamente o módulos? Esto para que el momento de crear un rol yo pueda seleccionar los módulos o los menús a los cuales tendrá acceso ese rol? así luego podría crear un usuario a asignarle ese un rol y al usuario darle permisos de crear, leer, editar, eliminar, ejecutar, imprimir y exportar...

Podrían orientarme o indicarme donde encontraría información de este tipo? o como podría realizarlo? He buscado pero un sistema de seguridad altamente dinámico siendo desarrollador Jr. Se me complica

Comment: Lectura obligatoria: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822 Intenta con otras palabras clave como "asp net role based menu". Que te de lo mismo si está en .net 2.0 con membership o si está con dotnet 8, ve por la lógica, dedícale tiempo a su análisis y podrás implementarlo con lo que quieras. Saludos.

Comment: @fredyfx gracias, he encontrado de hecho algo parecido a lo que quiero en .net 2.0

Comment: excelente, luego que intentes, editas la pregunta, colocas lo que has investigado, lo que has intentado, el error que tienes y con todos esos ingredientes, las chances de recibir respuesta, aumentan.